# Remove one JavaScript code and attach two JavaScript codes

Tags: javascript, stack-overflow, w3c, w3c-validation

I have these two JavaScript codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#patternForm').patternLock({
            fieldName: 'password'
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#patternForm').patternLock({
            timeout: 4000,
            drawEnd: function(value) {
                $('#generatedPatternT').text(value);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

How to add these in one code?

I want this:

```
$('#patternForm').patternLock({
    fieldName: 'password'
});
```

And this:

```
$('#patternForm').patternLock({
    timeout: 4000,
})
```

to be working.
And remove this code:

```
$('#generatedPatternT').text(value);
```

I don't know much about `JavaScript` so please help me

Comment: Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` function

```
$('#patternForm').patternLock({
    fieldName: 'password'
});
```

<s>setTimeout(function() { $('#patternForm').patternLock(); }, 4000);</s>

use : `window.onload`

```
window.onload = function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
        $('#patternForm').patternLock();
   }, 4000);
};
```

**UPDATE**

Got this code reference from [this site](http://codefoolz.com/patternlock/documentation/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#patternForm').patternLock({
        timeout: 4000,
        fieldName: 'password'
    });
});
```

Comment: @user8312352 updated my answer with `window.onload` try now

Comment: It is just a part of my web page: <div id="patternForm" name="password" value="<?=$password;?>"></div>
 <br>
<input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Login" />  
      </form>
     
<script type = "text/javascript">$('#patternForm').patternLock({ fieldName: 'password' }); setTimeout(function() { $('#patternForm').patternLock(); }, 4000);< /script>

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#patternForm').patternLock({
        timeout: 4000,
        fieldName: 'password'
    });
}); `This may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Just remove unnecessary code, merge it and put into single `script` tag:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#patternForm').patternLock({
      fieldName: 'password',
      timeout: 4000,
    });
  }); 
< /script>
```

Comment: @user8312352 have you checked your dev console?

Comment: Anyway you provided only partial code. It's hard to reason about what's happening there.

Comment: Can help me, if I give you download link for the full code?

Comment: @user8312352 sure